# On Google Chrome, is there a way to start with a new Google Account profile on Windows command line?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, user-accounts, user-profiles, command-line-arguments

I'm using public computers.

On Google Chrome, is there a way to start with a Google Account profile on Windows command line? This account is new to Chrome, since what I want is to login into a browser profile automatically.

If I save some configuration file, copy them to chrome data directory, and start chrome with some parameters, will it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can start chrome from command line in this way:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 5"
```

The profile folder is here:

```
C:\Users\#username#\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
```

I don't know if it's possible use a profile folder from e.g. a USB stick.